# jQuery makeDraggable with a little more finesse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

I've added a script from another question on SO to a solution I'm working with to enable the **jQueryUI Dialogs to be dragged outside the documents original boundaries**.

This is the script:

```
//Ensure jQuery windows can be pulled outside the browser boundaries.
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() {
    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        containment: false
    });
};
```

The problem is that when I add this, ***all* of the form becomes a drag-hande**. That makes it problematic when trying to scroll a dialog when the dialog begins a drag operation instead.

**How can I have just the dialog window titlebar as drag-handle (the original behaviour) but still get rid of the containment?**

**SOLUTION:**

```
//Ensure jQuery windows can be pulled outside the browser boundaries.
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() {
    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        containment: false,
        handle: ".ui-dialog-titlebar"
    });
};
```

Thank you Joseph!

Comment: ah I see.  Does this `containment: false` removes the ability to use drag handles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up using [drag handles](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle)